# Auto-discover exchange where username != email-address. Use URN rather than domain\username?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have an email I'm try to access through Microsoft.Exchanage.WebServices. Specifically, I'm trying to autodiscover the url. I run the following in Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyser (this works):

```
Email address: foooosoft.fiiztestmailbox@baaar.eu
Domain\User Name (or UPN): baaarnet\foooosoft.fiiztestma
         (foooosoft.fiiztestmailbox@baaar.eu also works)
Password: password1
```

This is because I've been told my username is foooosoft.fiiztestma because of a length limit for SAMAccountNames (20 characters).

**Trying to use my email address as the account name results in 401 errors. How do I change my code to take this into account?**

I've tried to supply "foooosoft.fiiztestma" to the WebCredentials constructor, but I get the same error.

**Alternatively, is there a way to cut to the chase and just supply the UPN (email address) rather than using domainname\username?**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string emailUser = "foooosoft.fiiztestmailbox@baaar.eu";
        string password = "password1";
        string domain = "baaarnet";

        var credentials = new WebCredentials(emailUser, password, domain);

        var foo = new ExchangeService
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            Url = DiscoverExchangeUrl(emailUser, credentials),
            TraceEnabled = false
        };
    }

    private static Uri DiscoverExchangeUrl(string emailAddress, ExchangeCredentials credentials)
    {
        var autoDiscover = new AutodiscoverService
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            EnableScpLookup = false,
            RedirectionUrlValidationCallback = url => true,
            TraceEnabled = false
        };

        var userSettings = autoDiscover.GetUserSettings(emailAddress, UserSettingName.ExternalEwsUrl);
        return new Uri(userSettings.Settings[UserSettingName.ExternalEwsUrl].ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried [Testing Exchange Autodiscover with PowerShell and the EWS Managed API](http://mikepfeiffer.net/2011/08/testing-exchange-autodiscover-with-powershell-and-the-ews-managed-api/) as well as most combinations of using the email as the user, domain\username, empty strings, not including the domain etc. I think it's time to do SMTP instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some luck providing the UPN as the user name and an empty string for domain name.